# How do do BLAS/cuBLAS treat the factors alpha and beta in their routines?

Tags: c, blas, algebra, cublas

Many linear algebra routines have constants such as alpha and beta as arguments. For example [cublas?GEMM](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cublas/index.html#cublas-level-3-function-reference) performs the following operation:

C := alpha*op( A )*op( B ) + beta*C

Suppose I set beta to 0.

1. Will the cuBLAS still perform an unnecessary scalar-matrix multiplication and matrix-matrix addition? What about other libraries such as BLAS/LAPACK/MKL?
2. If the necessary operations is not performed: Do I need to do something to ensure this, or is it avoided automatically?
3. Are there other values for alpha/beta for which there are other optimizations? For example, suppose I instead set beta=1, will scaling by beta operation be skipped?
4. Why does the [cuBLAS documentation](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cublas/index.html#cublas-lt-t-gt-gemm) and [BLAS documentation](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/520775) specify these factors in DGEMM as `const double` but in [examples](https://software.intel.com/en-us/mkl-tutorial-c-multiplying-matrices-using-dgemm) a `double` value is passed to them? What's the difference?

I would be surprised if these libraries did waste operations in the manner I described, but I didn't find an explicit discussion about it anywhere other than the cuBLAS documentation mentioning:

> if beta == 0 then C does not have to be a valid input.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even the reference implementation optimises here. No serious implementation with do the operation regardless of values for alpha or beta.

1. No it will not.
2. N/A
3. Just leave `beta=0.` to ignore C. `beta=1.` to skip scaling
4. The reason is compatibility with FORTRAN. There were no `const` variables in FORTRAN prior to F90. The BLAS interfaces were defined prior to F90 and everybody sticks to the conventions. I you want to have a C interface with proper keywords, look at the c-specific interfaces like `sblas_dgemm`.

Here is the reference implementation for `DGEMM`.
http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/d7/d2b/dgemm_8f_source.html. Look for `Quick return if possible.`, `And if  alpha.eq.zero.` etc